# Azure Cosmos DB Python SDK : Query items from change feed using checkpoints?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-cosmosdb

Newbie to the CosmosDB...please shed some light

@Matias Quaranta - Thank you for the samples

From the official samples it seems like the Change feed can be queried either from the beginning or from a specific point in time.

options["startFromBeginning"] = True
or
options["startTime"] = time

What other options does the QueryItemsChangeFeed method support?
Does it support querying from a particular check point within a partition?

Answer (score 0):

Glad the samples are useful. In theory, the concept of "checkpoints" does not exist in the Change Feed. "Checkpoints" is basically you storing the last processed batch or continuation after every execution in case your process halts.

When the process starts again, you can take your stored continuation and use it.

This is what the [Change Feed Processor Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor) and our [Azure Cosmos DB Trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#trigger) do for you internally.

To pass the continuation in python, you can use `options['continuation']` and you should be able to get them from the response headers on the `'x-ms-continuation'`.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the sample code [ReadFeedForTime](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-python/blob/master/samples/ChangeFeedManagement/Program.py), I has tried the options["startTime"]. But it doesn't work, the response is the same as the list of documents start from Beginning.